# Horovod Elasticity Adjust number of Workers in RunTime

Tags: docker, tensorflow, pytorch, mpi, horovod

I have been using Horovod using both TensorFlow and PyTorch in docker, every thing works fine under a fixed number of containers as explained in [Horovod docker](https://horovod.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docker_include.html)

I have checked the Horovod Elastic Demos [Horovod examples](https://github.com/horovod/horovod/tree/master/examples/elastic) but they doesn't show how to change the number of workers in runtime.

What I need is to know how to change the number of workers up or down by runtime?

Answer (score 1):

What you need for that is a Docker-specific host discovery that tells Elastic Horovod about all available containers. A generic way to do this is by using `horovodrun` and providing a host discovery script via `--host-discovery-script`. When invoked, the script returns a list of available hosts. See the [Running with horovodrun](https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/master/docs/elastic.rst#running-with-horovodrun) section of the [Elastic Horovod](https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/master/docs/elastic.rst) documentation.

In the near future there will be service provider specific host discoveries built into Horovod so users do not need to implement scripts for common providers.